# What particles does the space station have to worry about?

Tags: space-station, materials, physics

I've heard things like "even a paint chip can damage the space station" and I wanted to know to what extent that was true. I imagine the best characterization is what is the minimum momentum or kinetic energy of an object for it to be a concern for the space station. I'm sure this varies based on the material of the object and point of impact on the space station, but is there a general rule of thumb for this? And secondly, if a particle were traveling in the same orbit but opposite direction, what's the minimum mass that is concerning?

Comment: May be of using in constructing an answer: [Protecting the Space Station from Meteoroids and Orbital Debris](https://www.nap.edu/download/5532). If I get some time later I will try and write one.